# how to resolve 403 error in websocket on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, websocket, pythonanywhere

use the below code for connect websocket to kucoin exchange in pythonanywhere

```
import websocket
import requests

base_url = 'https://api.kucoin.com'
public_url_request = '/api/v1/bullet-public'

response = requests.post(base_url+public_url_request)
response_json = response.json()

token = response_json['data']['token']
end_point = response_json['data']['instanceServers'][0]['endpoint']


url_websocket = end_point + '?' + 'token=' + token

ws = websocket.create_connection(url_websocket)
print(ws.recv())
```

when run this code in my pc it's ok
but when run in pythonanywhere receive this error:

**raise WebSocketProxyException(
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketProxyException: failed CONNECT via proxy status: 403**

for websocket in kucoin first need to request and receive token.
in this example websocket url=**wss://ws-api.kucoin.com/endpoint?token=2neAiuYvAU61ZDXANAGAsiL4-iAExhsBXZxftpOeh_55i3Ysy2q2LEsEWU64mdzUOPusi34M_wGoSf7iNyEWJ-3A4b43Ywb3cgwf791yIZ9hw2RDfWICHtiYB9J6i9GjsxUuhPw3BlrzazF6ghq4L3TV21Wn2BhYdwCTcPMlmUw=.LT6TMHw9TEabisQiSNA_qQ==**

**note:** api.kucoin.com is in the
[whitelist](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/)

Answer (score 0):

Free accounts on PythonAnywhere can only access sites on a [whitelist](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/).  If the site that you're trying to connect to is an official public API, then it may be possible to add it to the list -- contact PythonAnywhere support, providing a link to the API docs.

Comment: api.kucoin.com is in the whitelist

Comment: How are you trying to connect to it? Free accounts are restricted to the HTTP protocol.